# React/Jest inst.render is not a function (no 'render' method defined)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to run tests using Jest, however I'm getting the following error, and I'm not quite sure why:

```
   Running 1 test suite...Warning: Component(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`, returned null/false from a stateless component, or tried to render an element whose type is a function that isn't a React component.
     FAIL  __tests__\images-test.js (0.867s)
    ● Images › it encountered a declaration exception
      - TypeError: inst.render is not a function
```

I'm using babel-core & loader ^6.0.0, babel-jest ^11.0.2

Here's my Jest Test file:

```
jest.autoMockOff();

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM, { render } from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import Images from './../src/Components/images';

describe('Images', () => {
    let mockData = {
        items: [
            {
                title: 'Test Title',
                media: {
                    m: 'http://www.testurl.com/test.jpg'
                }
            },
            {
                title: '2nd Test Title',
                media: {
                    m: 'http://www.testurl.com/test2.jpg'
                }
            }
        ],
        selectedImages: [],
        selectImage() { return false; }
    }

    const shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
    shallowRenderer.render(<Images 
                                items={mockData.items} 
                                selectedImages={mockData.selectedImages} 
                                selectImage={mockData.selectImage} />);

    it('Renders instance of div class=images in DOM', () => {
        expect(shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput().props.className).toEqual('images');
    });

    it('Renders child elements', () => {
        expect(shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput().props.children.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any stateless components you are rendering in this component?